# Can a set of real numbers be closed under division but not under addition, multiplication and subtraction?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, proof-writing

I have recently learned a bit about the concept of closure under an operation, and I'm curious to know if a set can be closed only under division (when considering the four basic arithmetic operations). It is clear to me that for a set $\Bbb{X}\subset\Bbb{R}$ to be closed under division:
$$1\in\Bbb{X},0\notin\Bbb{X}$$
which means that, for any real $k$:
$$k\in\Bbb{X}\iff\frac{1}{k}\in\Bbb{X}$$
And if $k\in\Bbb{X}\Rightarrow k^2=1$, then $\Bbb{X}$ is closed under division but also under multiplication, so if $\Bbb{X}$ is to be closed *only* under division:
$$\neg\forall k(k\in\Bbb{X}\Rightarrow k\in\Bbb{Z})$$
Which is to say, it is not the case that all members of $\Bbb{X}$ are integers.

This is about as far as I've gotten with restricting the possibilities. Where do I go from here?  Is the answer completely obvious?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Incidentally, I think something in your paragraph about whether members of $\mathbb{X}$ can be integers or not is misstated; the cases $k\in\mathbb{X}\implies k^2=1$ — that is, where $\mathbb{X}$ is $\{1\}$ or $\{-1, 1\}$ — are the two cases where all the members of $\mathbb{X}$ _are_ integers. Did you miss an 'if it is not the case' in your conditions there?

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Ah, you are right. I was thinking that for $\Bbb{X}$ to be ONLY closed under division, then $\Bbb{X}$ cannot be all integers. Confused myself :)

Comment: $X$ is closed under division and $a,b\in X$ then $\frac ab,\frac ba \in X$ and $\frac {\frac ab}a =\frac 1b\in X$ and $\frac {a}{\frac 1b}=ab\in X$.  So closure in division means closure in multiplication.... But not being closed in addition/subtraction is very easy.  Consider $\{p^k|k\in \mathbb Z\}$ for some prime $p$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $k, l\in\mathbb{X}$, then as you point out $\frac{1}{l}\in\mathbb{X}$, so that $\frac{k}{1/l} = kl\in \mathbb{X}$. So $\mathbb{X}$ must be closed under multiplication.

Comment: Both $2, 3 \in \mathbb{N} \cup \frac{1}{\mathbb{N}}$ but $\frac{2}{3} \not\in \mathbb{N} \cup \frac{1}{\mathbb{N}}$ so $\mathbb{N} \cup \frac{1}{\mathbb{N}}$ is not closed under division.  (A natural counterexample to being closed under addition or subtraction would be $\{ 2^n \mid n \in \mathbb{Z} \}$.)

Comment: And incidentally, a nonempty subset of $\mathbb{R}$ which does not contain 0 is *never* closed under subtraction.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps you.

I think your statement that $k\in\mathbb{X}$ iff $\frac{1}{k}\in\mathbb{X}$ doesn't mean that the set $\mathbb{X}$ is closed under division.

The reason why is because division is a binary operetion and the operation you've mentioned is a uniary operation

To be closed under an operation (in this case under division) is understood as $\frac{a}{b}\in\mathbb{X}$ every time that $a, b$ lie in $\mathbb{X}$.

Therefore, as @rogerl mentioned, let $\mathbb{X}$ to be a non-empty subset from real numbers that is closed under division. Since $\mathbb{X}$ is not empty, take $k\in\mathbb{X}$ and as a result from $\mathbb{X}$ to be closed under division $1=\frac{k}{k}\in\mathbb{X}$ then is closed under multiplication. Think of for instance in the set of rational positive numbers $\mathbb{Q}^{+}$ which is closed under division.

Remember that an operation over a set $X$ is just a function $f:X\times X\rightarrow X$.

Comment: Well, if $1$ is an element of the set, the set cannot be closed under division unless $1$ divided by every other member of the set is also a member of the set. What operation in my post is unary? And what does $f:X\times X\rightarrow X$ mean?

Comment: If the set is closed under division means that if $a, b\in X$ then $\frac{a}{b}\in X$ as well. Therefore, if $a\in X$ then $a, a\in X$ so $\frac{a}{a}\in X$ since $X$ is closed under division. And the operation you've mentioned is that if $k\in X$ then $\frac{1}{k}\in X$ which just depends on $k$ and not in two variables.
$f: X\times X\rightarrow X$ means that $f$ is a function from $X\times X$ to $X$. Which is to say  for every pair $(a, b)\in X\times X$ it associates a unique member $f(a, b)$ in $X$. For more details: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_operation